# Shortening string/array indexing

Tags: python

```
y = int(input())
for i in range(1, 9000):
    z = str(y+i)
    if z[0] != z[1] and z[0] != z[2] and z[0] != z[3] and z[1] != z[2] and z[1] != z[3] and z[2] != z[3]:
        print(z)
        break
```

Can i somehow shorten the `if z[0] != z[1] and z[0] != z[2] and z[0] != z[3] and z[1] != z[2] and z[1] != z[3] and z[2] != z[3]:` into checking if all indexes are different at once?

Comment: Create a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) from the array and then compare its length to the array's length.

Comment: @Itay Agreed. I have just implemented what you said as code in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that what i was looking for, thanks.
Also the code `if all(z[i] != z[j] for i in range(len(z)) for j in range(i + 1, len(z))):` of someone who deleted comment also worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z[0] != z[1] and z[0] != z[2] and z[0] != z[3] and z[1] != z[2] and z[1] != z[3] and z[2] != z[3]` simply means: Taking first 4 positions of the number string, none of the numbers occur in their following positions.
That means all numbers are unique. That means `len(set(z[:4])) == 4`:

```
y = int(input())
for i in range(1, 9000):
    z = str(y+i)
    if len(set(z[:4])) == 4:
        print(z)
        break
```

`input()` must be an at least 4 positions number to always have at least 4 positions for `z` (otherwise index out of bounds error).

```
y = int(input())
assert len(str(y)) >= 4
for i in range(1, 9000):
    z = str(y+i)
    if len(set(z[:4])) == 4:
        print(z)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a frequency list for each character and check the frequency list whether a character occur in different places.

```
freq =[0]*26 # For each character create 1 element

# Finding length of string z
n = len(z)  

for i in range(n):  
    # counting frequency of all characters  
    freq[ord(s[i])-97] += 1
```

then your freq list contains frequencies of all characters. So for example "aabbb" string will create [2,3,0,0,.....] list.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a string without repetition: comparing the list of the object to the its set will do. The current accepted answer does not work for other size than 4.

```
y = int(input())
print("y", y)
for i in range(1, 9000):
    z = str(y+i)
    digits_in_z = list(z)
    unique_digits_in_z = set(digits_in_z)
    if len(unique_digits_in_z) == len(digits_in_z):
        print(z)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
def valuesDistinct(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    s = set()
    for i in range(0, n):  
        s.add(arr[i])

    if len(arr) == len(s):
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
    
value = input("?")
print(valuesDistinct(value))
```

The function checks whether each element from an array (or each letter in a string) is distinct, returning `True` if they are distinct, and `False` if they are not.

I have created a set from the array, and then compared its length to the array's length. If they have the same length, it means the array is distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=len(z) 
flag=False
for i in range(0,n-1)
   for j in range(i+1, n) 

         if z[i]==z[j]
               flag=True
               break
  if flag==True
      break
       

if flag! =True
   Print(z)
```

The above for loops will compare every index values to all the values after it and if at any time that index value is equal to some  other value we assign flag true and break the loop and outside loop we check if flag is not true that means no index values was same and print it